# Bulk Products import are not showing on front end

Tags: magento-1.9, import, csv, import-products

I have uploaded bulk products through using a CSV file.  The products get uploaded successfully and can be found on the back end, but they are not showing on front end. When I edit a product and save it without any changes, it can then be found on the front-end. I cannot save each product as it is nearly 1000 products. I also reindex and flush cache without results. I am using Magento 1.9.2 version. What is the issue? Kindly any one help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have flat catalog enabled? If yes, disable if first and then run full reindex and flush cache and check if it is showing on front-end. If it will show then enable flat catalog again and do full re-indexing and flush cache and check.

Comment: I disable the flat catalogue, and reindex flush cache but no result

Comment: How you reindex? Also what is current indexing mode is set?

Comment: going to system -> index management then select all and reindex

Comment: Please try using ssh once, like php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall, run this command on you putty/ssh from root directory. As mostly this issue happen because of indexing, if you have indexing mode as "update on save" then whenever you will save product from admin it will re-index at the time of saving so product was showing on frontend.

Comment: yes I have update on save mode, do I need to change the mood?

Comment: Have you done the indexing using ssh? It will be better if you can change the mode to update on schedule as cron will update the changes.